# Scraping creators from a list of Youtube videos with certain amount of subscribers

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

This program is written in *Python* in the **Selenium** library, it generates a list of Youtube video links depending on what we typed in the search box. Is there any suggestion on how can I click on each one of these links and get another list of Youtube creators that have less than 500 subscribers?
I would appreciate a link to a similar solution or video that explains the analogical problem.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

#from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
#import requests



options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#All are optional
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
options.add_argument("--disable-Advertisement")
options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

driver= webdriver.Chrome(options=options)


#driver = webdriver.Chrome() 
#driver.implicitly_wait(10)

path = "https://youtube.com"
driver.get(path)

#xpath for search box
x_path_for_box = "/html/body/ytd-app/div[1]/div/ytd-masthead/div[4]/div[2]/ytd-searchbox/form/div[1]/div[1]/input"
searching_point_box = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value=x_path_for_box)

#user manual input
search_word = input("Enter the search keyword: ")
searching_point_box.send_keys(search_word)

#xpath for search button
x_path_search_button= "/html/body/ytd-app/div[1]/div/ytd-masthead/div[4]/div[2]/ytd-searchbox/button"
searchButton = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value=x_path_search_button)
searchButton.click()

new_path ="https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + search_word
driver.get(new_path)

item = []
SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 1
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")

item_count = 0

while item_count < 10:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.documentElement.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")

    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height
    


links = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, value = "a")

links


list_of_links = []
for link in links:
    #print(link.get_attribute("href"))
    href = link.get_attribute("href")
    list_of_links.append(href)
    
list_of_links
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think is just iterate for every link, open the link, check the followers with selenium and if checked the condition append the new link to a set of creators
Obviously you need to check the x_path, or see if other system is better

```
creators = set()
for link in list_of_links:
    driver.get(link)
    x_path_for_followers = '//*[@id="owner-sub-count"]'
    followers = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value=x_path_for_followers)
    nFollowers = getNumberOfFolowers(followers) # a duncion to parse from the text here to number
    if nFollowers > 500:
        continue
    x_path_for_creator = '//*[@id="text"]/a'
    creator = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value=x_path_for_creator)
    href = creator.get_attribute("href")
    creators.append(href)
```

Comment: it worked, thank you so much. I have  a small problem, i tried it on a clean list of links, but the list from  my code is actually getting every single link, like these, and i want simply links of videos, do you have a solution for it maybe?       
`https://www.youtube.com/about/
https://www.youtube.com/about/press/
https://www.youtube.com/about/copyright/
https://www.youtube.com/t/contact_us/
https://www.youtube.com/creators/
https://www.youtube.com/ads/`

Comment: i think all the links that start with "https://www.youtube.com/watch" are the links to videos?

Comment: yes, yes they are, I can  filter them out with regular expression, but not all the videos are scraped, do you have any suggestion what am I doing wrong, it is scrolling till the end, but it is not taking all the videos somehow?